# Flatten a list of nested dictionaries in PySpark

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark, nested, pyspark

I need to use PySpark to flatten the following RDD containing nested dicts, an example is as follows:

```
x = [{1: {345: 2}, 2: {33: 9}}, {5: {3: 2}, 2: {45, 9}}, {2: {33:5}}]
```

In the actual data I have, each nested dict may have varying length and number of items. `x` is just representative of the structure.

I need the output to be one single dictionary where the keys and values are merged as necessary:

```
x_out = {1: {345:2}, 2: {33: 14, 45:9}, 5: {3, 2}}
```

How can I achieve this? I tried flattening the RDD but I can't figure it out. I know that I must use combine and reduceByKey in same way.

This is not the same as the linked question which deals with tuples & lists.

Comment: can you try using the reduceByKey operation considering `1,2,5` as key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val listOfMap = List(Map(1 -> Map(345 -> 2), 2 -> Map(33 -> 9)),
  Map(5 -> Map(3 -> 2), 2 -> Map(45 -> 9)),
  Map(2 -> Map(33 -> 5))
)

var listOfTuples = new ListBuffer[((Int, Int), Int)]()

for(map <- listOfMap) {
  for(k1 <- map.keys) {
    for(k2 <- map(k1).keys) {
      listOfTuples += Tuple2((k1, k2), map(k1)(k2))
    }
  }
}

listOfTuples.toList.foreach(println(_))    

// transform input to be list of tuple 
val listOfTuples = List((1, (345, 2)), (2, (33, 9)), (5, (3, 2)), (2, (45, 9)), (2, (33, 5)))

// make rdd from input
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(listOfTuples)

// make the key of rdd as (first level key, second level key)
// the rdd becomes ((k1, k2), val)
// reduce the key by summing the vals
val rdd2 = rdd.map(pair => ((pair._1, pair._2._1), pair._2._2)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

// the key is the first level key, re-construct the map entry as val
// aggregate them by grouping key
val rdd3 = rdd2.map(pair => (pair._1._1, Map(pair._1._1 -> Map(pair._1._2 -> pair._2)))).groupByKey()

// flat map the previous rdd
val rdd4 = rdd3.flatMap(pair => pair._2)

rdd4.take(10).foreach(print(_))

// result
Map(1 -> Map(345 -> 2))Map(5 -> Map(3 -> 2))Map(2 -> Map(45 -> 9))Map(2 -> Map(33 -> 14))
```

Comment: While your solution is correct and I ran it in the Scala shell, I'm struggling to convert the first step (list of tuples) to Python. Nevertheless, thank you!

Comment: Hi, I include the code to transform the list of Map to list of Tuple.